My object appears all gray
So im new to blender and im trying to do a metallic 3d object for a graphic design project but when I get to the 3D rendering image my object appears in gray and I have no idea why.

Your scene has no light object and no HDRI for the environment, so it is only lit by the surrounding grey background. I would highly recommend watching at least a few beginner tutorials on lighting and rendering.
